# IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops not for production?

Tags: nservicebus

New to NServiceBus (4.7.5) and just implemented an NSB host.exe hosted service (implementing IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops) that detects changes to database tables and notifies subscribing web apps by publishing events, e.g. "CustomerDataWasUpdatedEvent". In the future we will perform the actual update through messagehandlers receiving commands obviously, but at the moment this publishing service just polls the database etc.

It all works well, however, approaching production, I noticed that David Boike, in his latest edition of "Learning NServiceBus", states that classes implementing 
IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops are really mostly for development and rarely used in production. I set up my database change detection in the Start method and it works nicely, does anyone know why this is discouraged?

Here is the comment in the actual book:

https://books.google.se/books?id=rvpzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=nservicebus+iwanttorunwhenbusstartsandstops+in+production+david+boike&source=bl&ots=U6sNII0nm3&sig=qIXffOVFhcy-_3qDnSExRpwRlD4&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=lHWRVc2_BKrWywPB65fIBw&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=nservicebus%20iwanttorunwhenbusstartsandstops%20in%20production%20david%20boike&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll copy the answer I gave in the [Particular Software Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/GKs4bhu2qR8)...

---

I'll quote myself directly here:

> An implementation of IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops is a great place to create a quick interface in order to test messages during debugging by allowing you to send messages based on the console input. Apart from this, it isn't common to have widespread use of them in a production system. One possible production use case will be to provision a resource needed by the endpoint at startup and then tear it down when the endpoint stops.

I think if I could add a little bit of emphasis it would be to "widespread use". I'm not trying to say you won't/can't have an IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops in production code or that avoiding them is a best practice. I am trying to say that having a ton of them is probably a code smell.

Above that paragraph in the book, I warn about IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops not having any ambient transactions or try/catch stuff going on. THAT is really the key part. If you end up throwing an exception in an IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops, tyou can run into big problems. If you use something like a .NET Timer and then throw an exception, you can crash your process!

Let me tell you how I screwed up on this in my first-ever NServiceBus system. The system (still in use today, from what I hear) is responsible for ingesting more than 3000 RSS feeds (probably a lot more than that now) into a CMS. So processing each feed, breaking it up into items, resizing images, encoding attached video for mobile ... all those things were handled in NServiceBus message handlers, which was scaled out to multiple servers, and that was all fantastic.

The problem was the scheduler. I implemented that as an IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops (well, actually IWantToRunAtStartup at that time) and it quickly turned into a mess. I kept the whole table worth of feed information in memory so that I could calculate when to fire off the next ProcessFeed command. I was using the .NET Timer class, and IIRC, I eventually had to use threading primitives like ManualResetEvent in order to coordinate the activity. And because I was using .NET Timer, if the scheduler threw an exception, that endpoint failed and had to restart. Lots of weird edge cases and it was always a quagmire of bugs. Plus, this was now a singleton "commander app" so while the feed/item processors could be scaled out, the scheduler could not.

As I got more experienced with NServiceBus, I realized that each feed should have been a saga, starting from a FeedCreated event, controlled through PauseProcessing and ResumeProcessing commands, using timeouts to control the next processing time, and finally (perhaps) ended via a FeedRemoved event. This would have been MUCH more straightforward and everything would have executed inside transactionally-controlled message handlers.

That experience led me to be a little bit distrustful/skeptical of IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops. Not saying it's bad, just something to be aware of. Always be prepared to consider if what you're trying to do couldn't be better accomplished in another way.

Answer (score 4):

The actual quote is:

> ...it isn't common to have widespread use of in a production system.

Uncommon is not the same thing as discouraged.

That said I do think there is intent here by the author to highlight the fact that further up the page they assert that this is not a good place to be doing lots of coding, as an unhandled exception can cause the whole process to fail.

The author actually does go on to mention a possible use case for when you may want to load a resource(s) to do work within the handler.

> Ok, maybe it's just this scenario we have that is a bit uncommon

Agreed - there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your approach. I recently did the same thing as you for wiring up SqlDependency to listen for database events and then publish a message as a result. In these scenarios there is literally nothing else you can do other than to use IWantToRunAtStatup.

Also, David himself often trawls the nservicebus tag, maybe he'll provide a more definitive answer than mine.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's just this scenario we have that is a bit uncommon. Normally the database inserts (this is more of a batch processing case than entities being changed by some business related event etc) would go through a command handler run within the NSB hosted service, in that case the IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Start method would just perform initialization of course, while actual work (updating db and publishing events) would be done in the handlers.

Comment: +1.  I do think your use case is uncommon--I'm guessing you run as a console app via a scheduler?  If so, I think that by itself is rather uncommon vs. running as a Windows service.  His last sentence in that linked paragraph exactly describes  what I use IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops for in production: to provision a resource or start a background process.  One current example is to start self-hosted WebAPI.